# Popup window for complex structured data in an extjs form field

Tags: forms, extjs

I need to build the following form field. Let's take the case where in a form I have multiple fields. Two of them are "last name" and "first name". Instead  of the classic way when these field will show seperatley I want a single fields thatt shows when completed like a text field with value a concatenqtion of e two values ( ie "michael jackson"). When I click on the field an window (like a picker date) will popup haing a form with the two fields.

Unfortunately i do not know where to start from:

- what class should I derive
- how should I store the value in the form ( two hidden values or just a serialized value of the fields).

I might have complex structure with 5-6 fields in this picker popup.

Answer (score 1):

I would extend Ext.form.field.Picker. In the createPicker() method you can crate whatever combination of fields an components that you want.

Re: storage of data, I'd serialze the values in the one field. Then you can treat reads and commits in the same way (and you can always manipulate the data later.

Here's an example that I did a while back:  jsfiddle.net/existdissolve/wMcQk/

Comment: Nice. Looks promising. In your example, when i click on the field to edit it, there is one second where the json show in the textfield.